# Bitrix выборк инфоблока в контенте

Tags: битрикс

Здравствуйте!
Не понимаю как применить имеющийся инфоблок к любой странице.
Если следующий путь:
Рабочий стол->Контент->Услуги->Грузчики

1 вкладка "Значения свойств:" можно поставить галочку "Заказ услуги" и добавляется "Заказ услуги" на страницу. Представляет из себя кнопку по которой открывается форма.

Как можно сделать что бы это поле "Заказ услуги" можно выбрать на любой странице контента?

Рабочий стол Контент Инфоблоки Типы инфоблоков Контент Услуги
В свойствах имеется Заказ услуги типа "список" и код FORM_ORDER
Добавляю аналогичный пункт в другой инфоблок - появляется Заказ услуги но как обычный список а не галочка выбора.

Comment: Что? Где? Как? Что такое раздел "Значения свойств"? Где он находится? Разделом чего является? Инфоблока? Сайта? что такое галочка "Заказ услуги", где вы ее отмечаете? Публичная часть сайта? Админка? При чем здесь "Грузчики"? Если вы спрашиваете про "Заказ услуги"? Это два разных инфоблока или что? Прочтите [как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и поправьте свой

Comment: К сожалению с битриксом не то что "хороший сайт" не сделать с ним даже "хороший вопрос" невозможно задать. Так что это максимальное описание. Есть путь (см. вопрос). В первой вкладке есть "значения свойств" которые есть у всех страниц контента. У контента типа услуги есть там галочка "заказ услуги". У остальных нет. Как узнать где оно добавляется и как это добавить в остальные типы - вот что мне нужно.

Comment: с кривыми руками не создашь. Я уже 3 года работаю с решениями Битрикс. И хороших сайтов более чем достаточно. Вопрос задать легко, нужно лишь понять что нужно. Добавить в остальные типы чего? Инфоблоков. Есть настройка типов инфоблоков. Там у каждого инфоблока есть вкладка "Свойства", где добавляются свойства инфоблока.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял свойства привязано к инфоблоку "Услуги"

Если вам нужно создать такое же свойство в других типах инфоблоков:

1. Зайдите во вкладку Инфоблоки->Типы инфоблоков->выберете нужный
2. Вкладка "Свойства", там хранятся все свойства добавленые пользователем
3. Создайте новое (можно скопировать параметры из инфоблока "Услуги"
4. При редактировании материала выводим новое свойство http://prntscr.com/iv72et

Но если это новое свойство для инфоблока нужно будет еще настраивать шаблон, чтобы вывести какой-то блок на сайте